# HTML E-Mails are being sent out as plaintext

Tags: 8, emails

I am  using the Swift mailer module to send HTML emails. My actual body in `hook_mail_alter()` is the following.

```
    <p><em><strong>New Enquiry Appear </strong></em></p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="77" width="467">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 228px;">お名前</td>
            <td style="width: 258px;">@name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 228px;">&nbsp;メールアドレス</td>
            <td style="width: 258px;">@email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 228px;">&nbsp;電話番号</td>
            <td style="width: 258px;">@mobile</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 228px;">題名</td>
            <td style="width: 258px;">@title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 228px;">メッセージ本文</td>
            <td style="width: 258px;">@message</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

The actual output is something like the following.

```
    /*New Enquiry Appear */

お名前
                        amol


                         メールアドレス
                        testl@gmail.com


                         電話番号
                        99888776655


                        題名
                        challawar
               Html tag are not converted in Bold and Italic.


                        メッセージ本文
                        sssssssssssssssss
```

I want my output to be well formatted as per my HTML markup. (Few HTML tags like `<br />`, `<strong>`, and `<table>` are not working in the above example.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the message setting of swiftmailer module? You can change the message format to HTML.

Comment: @Aniket i have check that

Comment: in mailsystem module setting, change the theme, then it should work. If it still not work, then try adding following code in your mail alter
$message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes';

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link [module configuration link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1590180). It has option of sending email either as Plain Text or HTML. Please re-verify that settings.

Comment: I have already check that .

Answer (score 0):

In .module file use the following code

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function hook_mail_alter(&$message) { 

$message['body'][1] = Markup::create($message['body'][1]);

}
```